# SQL Server trigger on update with select then insert into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to  create a trigger on update of a column and insert rows into other tables. The data is coming from a `SELECT` with multiple joins and needs to be inserted into multiple tables.

My question is, is it best practice to insert the values into variables before the insert? I have never created a trigger like this before.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ship_trigger ON dbo.Orders
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF ( UPDATE(OrderStatusId) AND OrderStatusId == 1)
BEGIN

SELECT
FROM
JOIN
JOIN
WHERE
```

I am just looking to understand the most efficient way to insert the data into the other tables

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also, how would you use the variables?

Comment: SQL Server. Well i thought i might need to use the variables in order to do the insert. By no means am i a db guy. I am a programmer who knows some sql.  i have never done a select and then inserted from there. only the opposite( insert column select value from).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL Server (the syntax suggests so), it isn't a best practice to insert the values into variables first, what would be the point of doing that?. And the only way that you **could** actually do that would be on table variables or if you update only one row, since the triggers gets executed once for all the rows that got affected by your `UPDATE`, and those rows are available to you on the `INSERTED` pseudo table. So, your trigger would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ship_trigger ON dbo.Orders
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF ( UPDATE(OrderStatusId) AND OrderStatusId = 1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO SomeTable(Col1, Col2)
    SELECT Col1, Col2
    FROM INSERTED

END
```